# finding current location in Swift Xcode 7.3

Tags: xcode, swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I am currently working on a project that requires me to get the users location in the app. Originally i had coded it to just show a working map view, but then wanted to make it show the users location.I keep getting the error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on the line

> self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.delegate = self

        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Location Delegate Methods

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let location = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location!.coordinate.latitude, location!.coordinate.latitude)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span:MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

Comment: Most likely cause: self.mapView is nil because it's not connected to the Map View in Interface Builder

Answer (score 0):

This Might help you.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var latitude = 0.00;
var Longitude = 0.00;




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestLocation()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location11 = locations.first {
        print("Found User's location: \(location11)")
        print("Latitude: \(location11.coordinate.latitude) Longitude: \(location11.coordinate.longitude)")
        latitude = location11.coordinate.latitude
        Longitude = location11.coordinate.longitude
        startConnection()
    }
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Failed to find user's location: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

 }
```

Add permissions in you plist file.

Comment: The specific keys you would want to add to your project's: target: info.plist for niks290192's example above would be:
`Privacy - Location Always Usage Description` and 
`Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description`
Values should be a string message briefly describing to a user why your app requires location services.  More info at: https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager